# $Aut(X)$ and $Bir(X)$ for Calabi-Yau 3-folds with $\rho(X)=1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, calabi-yau

Let $X$ be a Calabi-Yau 3-fold with Picard number one. How can one show that the automorphism group $Aut(X)$ is finite and moreover coincides with the birational automorphism group $Bir(X)$?

It seems this is a well-knwon fact, but I cannot find any reference. Since any automorphism group of $X$ preserves the ample generator of $Pic(X)$, this question should reduce to the projective geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The group $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is finite because, as you point out, it preserves a very ample line bundle; hence it is an algebraic group (a closed subgroup of a projective group).  Therefore it suffices to prove that its Lie algebra $H^0(X,T_X)$ is trivial. By Serre duality this is dual to $H^3(X,\Omega ^1_X)=H^{1,3}$, which is conjugate to $H^{3,1}=H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, which is trivial by definition of Calabi-Yau varieties.

Now since $K_X$ is trivial, any birational automorphism is an isomorphism outside sets of codimension $\geq 2$ (see for instance [here, p. 2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1013.pdf) for a much more general statement).
This implies again that it preserves a very ample line bundle, hence that it is biregular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question about the last statement. How do you know the map is biregular if it preserve the a very ample line bundle?

Comment: Let $u$ be a birational map, $L$ very ample, $u^*L\cong L$. Then $u$ induces a linear automorphism of $V:=H^0(X,L)$; the embedding $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}(V^*)$ defined by $L$ is equivariant w.r.t. $(u,u^*)$. But this means that $u$ is induced by an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$, hence is biregular.

Answer (score 0):

Even though an (very good) answer was already accepted, if you want to know more on automorphism and birational groups of Calabi - Yau 3 folds you can look at papers by Keiji Oguiso.

Comment: It might help if you were to link to one or two that you think would be helpful.